# ASP.Net Masterpage and jQuery creates duplicate content

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, master-pages

I have a ASP.Net masterpage with jQuery tabs.

I am trying to set it up like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Settings.aspx"">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</div>
```

The contentplaceholder's div is inside the tab div to make the jQuery tabs surround the content. Unfortunately, jQuery duplicates all the content of the master page when turning this into real jQuery tabs:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Are you using some kind of tabs plug in? if not then what does tabs() function do? What do you mean duplication here? Can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is that JQuery tabs changes the visibillity of three divs whose content is loaded in the page.
Not different pages as you use.

So if what you want, is to take advantage of JQuery ui CSS for your tabs.

Then the simple way of doing it is to copy the classnames into the li-tags and make some server side logic to change the class for active / inactive tabs.
i have done this myself for a MVC solution where I wanted the layout to be consistent and therefore chose JQuery UI.

Something along the way of:

```
    <li><a href="Default.aspx" class="ui-tabs... ui-... <%
    if(HttpContext.current.url.contains("Default.aspx"))%><%:ui-active-tab%><%
    %>" >Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Settings.aspx" class="ui-tabs... ui-... <%
    if(HttpContext.current.url.contains("Settings.aspx"))%><%:ui-active-tab%><%
    %>" >Settings</a></li>
```

the syntax is written from memory, both C# and class names. So please forgive me for errors in this respect.

Hope I guessed your problem right.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the jQuery UI tabs plugin, but from what I see in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#default), you should have a div per tab, and the anchors should link to the id's of the individual divs:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems you only have one div... I don't see how you want this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am programming this site with Erlend D.. The problem is that we want the tabs to be the main menu of the page, so a master page is the way to go. How do you incorporate the "children" of the master page into those divs?

For example:
If you have the pages: one.aspx, two.aspx and three.aspx, and you want the jqueryui tabs in the master page to link to those pages, how would one do that?

Comment: The problem is that jQuery UI tabs isn't designed to work like this. There is a way to only load the data of one page initially though, and let the other ones being loaded using ajax. See [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) for an example.