# jquery add on page load show requested tab feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I'm a newbie with jquery and i've used this code for tabs

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
        tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

        $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
            tabContainers.hide();
            tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
            $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            return false;
        }).filter(':first').click();
    });


</script>
```

What i need is to be able to load a specific tab when open a url like:
www.mysite.com/page.html#tab1

html link looks like this:

```
<a href="#tab1" class="selected">name link</a>
<a href="#tab2" class="">name link2</a>
<a href="#tab3" class="">name link3</a>
```

I've tryied lots of scripts, but maybe is my fault (i'm a dude with javascript)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need an anchor like `<a href="#tab1">click to see tab1</a>`
2. You need to redirect the user to #tab1 so you have to remove the `return false;` line of your function wich disables the redirecting
3. Your function is being triggered when the `<a>` is clicked, you need to trigger it once more when the page is being loaded

your function will look like this

```
$(function(){
    onClickHandler = function() {
      $('div.tabs > div').hide();
      $(window.location.hash).show();
    }
    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(onClickHandler);
    onClickHandler();
});
```

Comment: thank you, this works but now i've to click on tabs twice to go to the tab!

Comment: $(function () {
   var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
   tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();
   
   $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
    tabContainers.hide();
    tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
   /* return false; */
   }).filter(':first').click();
   onClickHandler = function() {
      $('div.tabs > div').hide();
      $(window.location.hash).show();
    }
    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(onClickHandler);
    onClickHandler();




  });

Comment: and now the first tab doesn't open when the page is loaded

Answer (score 1):

JQuery-UI have a [tab-widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) You can use.

Much simpler and more stable than writing your own.

For different URL's please have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363074/asp-net-masterpage-and-jquery-creates-duplicate-content/5365325#5365325).

It tells you how to leverage on the UI-themes and load different URl's.

Otherwise You have to do a `$('#theIdOfTheDiv').load(url)` on the click event in the tab

Comment: there's nothing about request a tab via url

Answer (score 0):

The tab you want displayed by default should have a class of `selected` in your HTML. So should the associated content wrapper. The others should not.

Answer (score 0):

window.location has a hash attribute. So, you can check it against the empty string and if it's not empty, select that tab:

```
if(!window.location.hash === "")
    $(window.location.hash).show();
```